# How can I make the text of a UIBarButtonItem wrap to two lines?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Some of the titles of view controllers in my UINavigationController are quite long, which makes the back button in the navigation bar of the next view controller in the hierarchy miss out some of the text, with a "..." instead.

How could I make the text of the back button wrap onto two lines, as with "Now Playing" in the navigation bar of iPod.app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the UIBarButtonItem method initWithCustomView: then set the rightBarButtonItem property in UINavigatiobItem.

Comment: thanks- I was hoping not to have to reimplement the drawing code for the pointy button, but I guess I'll have to!