# UIBarButtonItem width with a two-line label

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to know how can I get rid of spaces to the left and right from a two-line label in UIBarButtonItem, which has its view set by setCustomView as follows:

```
UIButton* forwardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];

[forwardButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)];

[forwardButton setTitle:@"Now\nPlaying" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[forwardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openPlayer) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[forwardButton.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];

[navButton setCustomView:forwardButton];
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtjrdsogo7taffi/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-01%20at%201.16.41%20PM.png) is the result I get.

The width of the button is as if the label had text written in one line like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6iodu6q0p8ntgg/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-01%20at%201.17.19%20PM.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the bounds for the button.

```
UIButton* forwardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
[forwardButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)];

[forwardButton setTitle:@"Now\nPlaying" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[forwardButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];

forwardButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);


UIBarButtonItem* forwardButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: forwardButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = forwardButtonItem;
```

tested this and works

Comment: thanks, It really works, I tried setting bounds before setting the title =___="

Comment: One more problem appeared. The solution works only with navigation bar style set to default, if i try black the width problem reappears. Tried setting style before and after the solution code as well as setting it in the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString   *titleStr=@"Now\Playing";
BarButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

[BarButton setTitle:titleStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: @AlimovAndrei- use BarButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: @AlimovAndrei- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926732/how-can-we-put-two-line-in-uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar

Comment: setting lines to 0 doesn't change anything, the rendering of the label in the answer you gave works, but the answer Bogus gave is more simple