# How to make bar button items have 2 lines of text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I try to follow this one, but it doesn't work.

[How can we put two line in UIBarButtonItem in Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926732/how-can-we-put-two-line-in-uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar)

I don't know why the button view I created and assigned to the bar button item cannot display at all?

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[button1 setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"REQUEST\nEQUIPMENT", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 sizeToFit];
self.barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button1];
```

**Or is there any better way to have more than 1 line of text in the UIBarButtonItem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a bar button item but you are never putting it into the interface. Setting `self.barButtonItem` doesn't put the bar button item into the interface; it just retains the bar button item. This has nothing at all to do with the "two-line" question. You cannot make *any* bar button item appear by doing what you're doing.

A bar button item appears when, say, you are a view controller in a navigation interface and you set `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` to your bar button item. But you are not doing that.